# positive Integer value of $n$ for which $2005$ divides $n^2+n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How Can I calculate positive Integer value of $n$ for which $2005$
>   divides $n^2+n+1$

My try:: $2005 = 5 \times 401$

means $n^2+n+1$ must be a multiple of $5$ or multiple of $401$

because $2005 = 5 \times 401$

now $n^2+n+1 = n(n+1)+1$

now $n(n+1)+1$ contain last digit $1$ or $3$ or $7$

$\bullet $ if last digit of $n(n+1)+1$ not contain $5$. So it is not divisible by $5$

Now how can I calculate it? please explain it to me.

Answer (score 6):

If a number is divisible by $2005=5\cdot401,$ it must be divisible by $5$ and by $401$

Now, as you have identified $n^2+n+1$ is not divisible by $5,$ it can not be divisible by  any multiple of $5$ like  $2005=5\cdot401$

---

Alternatively,

$$n^2+n+1\equiv0\pmod {2005}\implies n^2+n+1\equiv0\pmod 5$$

$$\implies 4(n^2+n+1)\equiv0\pmod 5\implies (2n+1)^2\equiv-3\equiv2$$

Now, $(\pm1)^2\equiv1\pmod 5,(\pm2)^2\equiv4$

So, there is no solution to $ (2n+1)^2\equiv-3\pmod 5$

Answer (score 0):

A number of the form $n^2+n+1$ has divisors of the form 3, or any number of $6n+1$, and has a three-place period in base n.

On the other hand, there *are* values where 2005 divides some $n^2+n-1$, for which the divisors are of the form n, 10n+1, 10n+9. This happens when n is 512 or 1492 mod 2005.